# Ajax function only working with alert()

Tags: javascript, ajax, responsetext

I'm trying to get AJAX to read a text file(which works) but it will only display the `responseText` if I have an `alert()` in the function(which I don't want).

Is there a way to get it to displa the `responseText` without an `alert()`? This is my current code.

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
         function load(){
             var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
             txtFile.open("GET", "current.txt", true);
             txtFile.send(null);
             document.write(txtFile.responseText);
         }
    window.onload = load;
    </script>
```

Comment: To my understanding the responseText is simply a string, so it should be applicable anywhere you use strings. What if you create a div with id="test", and do this document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = txtFile.responseText; What happens then?

Comment: Also, I can warmly recommend the jQuery ajax functions. Easy to implement, easy to use and cross-browser optimized.

Comment: not really sure what that is supposed to do, but it didn't work.

Comment: You should never use `document.write` after onload! I also think this is the 5th post today using XMLHttpRequest in a synch manner when it is async.

Answer (score 1):

Change the .open method to false so as not use async. If true, assign a callback handler to the `onreadystatechange` property to determine when the call has completed. Adding a alert was adding a sufficient wait for the file to return so it worked.

```
txtFile.open("GET", "current.txt", false);
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536648(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea what to use, or what they were :P